# How to duplicate a SSL_CTX object in a TLS application?

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl

I am having a application in. c that uses openssl for TLS v1.2 implemention.

The application shall open multiple remote connections to remote server running with the same version of TLS. I have a single set of key, certificate and CA_certificate to be used for all connections.

I need to maintain the `SSL_CTX` object for each client separately. But, I wish to create a single global `SSL_CTX` context object and configure it once for the following:

- SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto()
- SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file()
- SL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file()
- SSL_CTX_set_verify()
- SSL_CTX_set_options()
- SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations
- SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth()

And then, for each connections initiated by the application, I can duplicate (make a copy) of the above configured context ctx and call `SSL_new()` directly, without going through the listed steps over and over for each client.

Does Openssl provide any function to duplicate the `SSL_CTX` object?
If not is there any other safe way to do so? like `memcpy`() etc.

Comment: Please don’t tag questions both C and C++ unless the question is specifically about both of them. They’re completely different languages.

Comment: *"I need to maintain the SSL_CTX object for each client separately."* - why? This would only be needed if the CTX should be different. If they are the same they can simply be shared.

Comment: By default the SSL_CTX configuration shall be same. However, in the long run, the context for individual may need different parameters like compression, TLS version changes etc. between diferent clients.Thats why, instead of calling SSL_CTX_new() and all listed functions in the question for each client, only the clients that deviates from the default shall modify the SSL_CTX according to their requirements. Hence. my question of making a duplicate rather than sharing the same context.

Answer (score 1):

`SSL_CTX` has a counting reference. It means it will be freed when its reference counts reaches zero.

So rather than copying `SSL_CTX`, just increase its reference by `SSL_CTX_up_ref()` and use same object. As a result, your code will be something like this:

```
SSL_CTX *g_ssl_ctx = nullptr;
//...
//init g_ssl_ctx 
//...
SSL_CTX *get_client_ctx() {
    SSL_CTX_up_ref(g_ssl_ctx);
    return g_ssl_ctx;
}
```

Comment: Or just do multiple `SSL_new` (one for each connection) on the same `SSL_CTX` and it effectively does this for you.

Comment: I want to avoid multiple SSL_CTX_new() + the list of functions for each client as most of them shall follow the default context settings. But, I cannot share the same context with all connections as there is a possibility of updating the settings for some clients like compression, TLS version etc may change in the future between different clients. So. I need to have separate SSL_CTX for each connection and yet avoid repeated calls to the same functions. If, I could simply duplicate teh global ctx for each connection, I would be able to modify the parameters without modifying the global ctx.